# Custom fields value in Woocommerce product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking through answers on how to get this work but can't find a solution that works.

I have organised my plugins so that each upload automatically generates a custom field value depending on the uploaded information.

[Screenshot of custom fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giOFE.png)

I want it to be so that when I type the field name, i.e "track_bpm" into the description or short description of a product in Woocommerce that it then shows the value. That way I can automate the creation of product pages. Currently, it doesn't change.

I've added:

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        if ( flatsome_product_block( get_the_ID() ) ) {
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom' );
        } else {
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
        }
        ?>

<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

To the single-product.php file in the loop with the 'key' value replaced with each custom field name, but this just adds the value to the top or bottom of the page depending on the location in the loop.

Any advice here would be really appreciated!